# Application deployed in docker container becomes unavalable for http calls after updating to .NET 8

Tags: docker, http, gitlab-ci, .net-8.0

I had two apps targeted to .NET 7 which run in Docker containers managed by docker-compose and all were going fine before I updated them up to .NET 8.

Apps run just fine in containers, no error appears in logs, but apps stop to respond via http. I didn't change dockerfiles, compose config or environment as well, just changed .NET 7 to .NET 8 where needed.

It seems there is some network issue, what should I check?

Comment: ASP.NET now listens on port 8080 rather than port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hans Kilian, I've figured that out.
I had to edit docker-compose.yml the next way, from

```
version: "3"
services:
  service1:
    container_name: serv1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service1/Dockerfile
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/serv1:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/config/appsettings1.json:/app/appsettings.json

  service2:
    container_name: serv2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service2/Dockerfile
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/serv2:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "401:80"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/config/appsettings2.json:/app/appsettings.json
```

to

```
version: "3"
services:
  service1:
    container_name: serv1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service1/Dockerfile
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/serv1:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/config/appsettings1.json:/app/appsettings.json

  service2:
    container_name: serv2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service2/Dockerfile
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/serv2:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "401:8080"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/config/appsettings2.json:/app/appsettings.json
```

So, I've just changed the ports mapping from `:80` to `:8080`. Hope this will help somebody not to get frustrated.

---

[Breaking change: Default ASP.NET Core port changed from 80 to 8080](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port)

Here is the summary (*and for case if the link somehow is broken*):

> ## Default ASP.NET Core port changed from 80 to 8080
>
> The default ASP.NET Core port configured in .NET container images has
> been updated from port 80 to 8080.
>
> We also added the new `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` environment variable as
> a simpler alternative to `ASPNETCORE_URLS`. The new variable expects a
> semicolon delimited list of ports numbers, while the older variable
> expects a more complicated syntax.
>
> Apps built using the older
> xref:Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder?displayProperty=nameWithType
> API won't respect the new `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` environment
> variable. And now that `ASPNETCORE_URLS` is no longer set
> automatically, they'll switch to use a default URL of
> `http://localhost:5000`, rather than `http://*:80`, as formerly.
>
> ### Previous behavior
>
> Prior to .NET 8, you could run a container expecting port 80 to be the
> default port and be able to access the running app.
>
> ### New behavior
>
> Starting with .NET 8, if you map to port 80 in the container without
> explicitly setting the ASP.NET Core port used in the container to 80,
> any attempt to connect to that mapped port will fail.
>
> If you are using
> [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/connect-applications-service/)
> or [Docker
> Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#ports),
> you will need to change the port per those schemas. See [Using .NET
> with
> Kubernetes](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/kubernetes/README.md)
> for examples.
>
> ### Version introduced
>
> .NET 8 Preview 1
>
> ### Type of change
>
> This change is a behavioral
> change.
>
> ### Reason for change
>
> The change to the port number was made because of the need to provide
> a good usability experience when switching to a `non-root` user.
> Running as a `non-root` user requires the use of a non-privileged port
> in some environments. Since port 80, the previous default port, is a
> privileged port, the default was updated to port 8080, which is a
> non-privileged port.
>
> ### Recommended action
>
> There are two ways to respond to this breaking change:
>
> - Recommended: Explicitly set the `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS`, `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS`, and `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variables
>   to the desired port. Example: `docker run --rm -it -p 9999:80 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80 <my-app>`
> - Update existing commands and configuration that rely on the expected default port of port 80 to reference port 8080 instead. Example:
>   `docker run --rm -it -p 9999:8080 <my-app>`
>
> If your app was built using the older
> xref:Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder?displayProperty=nameWithType
> method, set `ASPNETCORE_URLS` (not `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS`). Example:
> `docker run --rm -it -p 9999:80 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:80 <my-app>`
>
> ### Affected APIs
>
> None.